# getTotal() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Tags: python

So, here is my Shoping Cart code, im stuck with this code, i fix one error, another pop out. So now i get TypeError: getTotal() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

```
class Item():
"""Name and price of Item"""
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

    def getName(self):            #Returning item's name
        return self.name

    def getPrice(self):           #Returning item's price.
        return self.price

class User():
"""Getting name of user"""
    def __init__(self, name,budget):
        self.name = name
        self.budget = budget

    def userName(self):               #Returning user's name
        return self.name

    def userBudget(self):             #Returning user's budget
        return self.budget

class Cart():
"""Creating a cart, you can add item in cart and remove it, also u can se your total bill."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.carta = []   #Carta is shopping cart.

    def addItem(self,carta):
        self.carta.append(1)  #Adding item in cart.

    def getTotal(self,carta):  #Total bill.
        total = 0
        for item in carta:
            item = getPrice, getName
            total += item
        return total

    def numItems(self,carta):    #Number of items in cart.
        self.carta = carta.len()
        return len.carta()

def kart():
    item1 = Item ("Iphone", 500)
    item2 = Item ("Samsung", 200)
    item3 = Item("Huawei", 400)
    uname = User("Marko", 2000)
    kart = Cart()
    kart.addItem(item1)
    kart.addItem(item2)
    kart.addItem(item3)
    print ("Hi %i, your total bill is $%0.2f, and you have %i items in your cart.",uname.userName(), kart.getTotal(), kart.numItems())

final = kart()
print (final)
```

Output i get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Marko\Documents\Projects\Shopping.py", line 56, in <module>
final = kart()
File "C:\Users\Marko\Documents\Projects\Shopping.py", line 54, in kart
print ("Hi %i, your total bill is $%0.2f, and you have %i items in your cart.",uname.userName(), kart.getTotal(), kart.numItems())
TypeError: getTotal() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Every tip, every help is welcome, thanks,

Comment: The error tells you exactly what is wrong and where. What is confusing you about that message?

Comment: `kart.getTotal()` - that rather looks like a call with _zero_ parameters to me ...

Comment: @CBroe the `self` parameter is implicit. Don't add to the confusion.

Comment: @Boldewyn wasn’t trying to. Don’t know the specifics of how this works, just pointing out what seemed to be an obvious mistake from the code shown.

Comment: This won't even run with the indentation as given.

Comment: You don't need most of those getters. Python isn't Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a several errors in your classes.

First, in Python, you can ger rid of `getXXX()` methods, especially in your case. So, you can redefine `Item` and `User` classes as:

```
class Item():
    """Name and price of Item"""
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

class User():
    """Getting name of user"""
    def __init__(self, name,budget):
        self.name = name
        self.budget = budget
```

---

In the `Cart` class, that code does not what you want:

```
def addItem(self,carta):
    self.carta.append(1)  #Adding item in cart.
```

It will append the integer `1` into the current `cart`. To do as you would, take into account the current item to add:

```
def addItem(self, item):
    self.carta.append(item)
```

Next, `getTotal` cannot work as it is:

```
def getTotal(self, carta):  # carta is not needed
    total = 0
    for item in carta:  # work with the current carta, so use self.carta
        item = getPrice, getName  # I guess you want to retrieve the item's price, so use item.price
        total += item
    return total
```

Finally, `numItems` cannot work too (!). If you want to find the carta [length](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) (as `carta` is a list), do that:

```
def numItems(self):    #Number of items in cart.
    return len(self.carta)
```

---

Final code with fixes and a right `print` statement:

```
class Item():
    """Name and price of Item"""
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

class User():
    """Getting name of user"""
    def __init__(self, name,budget):
        self.name = name
        self.budget = budget

class Cart():
    """Creating a cart, you can add item in cart and remove it, also u can se your total bill."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.carta = []   #Carta is shopping cart.

    def addItem(self, item):
        self.carta.append(item)  #Adding item in cart.

    def getTotal(self):  #Total bill.
        total = 0
        for item in self.carta:
            total += item.price
        return total

    def numItems(self):    #Number of items in cart.
        return len(self.carta)

def test_kart():
    item1 = Item ("Iphone", 500)
    item2 = Item ("Samsung", 200)
    item3 = Item("Huawei", 400)
    uname = User("Marko", 2000)
    kart = Cart()
    kart.addItem(item1)
    kart.addItem(item2)
    kart.addItem(item3)
    print('Hi %s, your total bill is $%0.2f, and you have %i items in your cart.' % (uname.name, kart.getTotal(), kart.numItems()))

test_kart()
```

We can do a lot more pythonic, but it seems you are learning Python, so try to understand that snippet correctly and then try to optimize, if wanted and needed. And read [that tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) :)

Answer (score 0):

The class `Cart` already wraps the list of items contained in the cart. You don't need to pass any argument to `getTotal`. The call is correct; the definition is not.

`addItem` *does* need an argument, but it's the item to add to the cart, not the cart itself. Your current implementation only adds the number 1 to the cart on each call, not the first argument.

Likewise, `numItems` just needs to return the length of `self.carta`, not take any additional arguments.

```
class Cart:
"""Creating a cart, you can add item in cart and remove it, also u can se your total bill."""

    def __init__(self):
        self.carta = []

    def add_item(self, item):
        self.carta.append(item)

    def get_total(self):
        total = 0
        for item in self.carta:
            total += item.price
        return total

    def num_items(self):
        return len(self.carta)
```

Python isn't Java. You don't need to define separate functions for simple attribute access (as I've hinted by my definition of `get_total` above, accessing `item.price` directly).

```
class Item:
"""Name and price of Item"""
    def __init__(self, name, price):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

class User:
"""Getting name of user"""
    def __init__(self, name,budget):
        self.name = name
        self.budget = budget
```

Finally, you want to either *return* (not print) a string from `kart`, or dispense with the `final=...`/`print(final)` pair.

Answer (score -1):

Well, in your print you call `kart.getTotal()` but in the definition of Cart, you have this method `def getTotal(self,carta)`. 
So when you call it you have to pass 2 arguments.

You only pass one wich is `kart`. So if i understood properly what you're trying to do you have to change the method getTotal to `def getTotal(self)` as you don't use the parameter carta